# Overlook modified files in git?

Tags: git

Can i tell git to ignore *tracked* files that it shouldn't touch? Changes to them should be protected from getting into the repository by default actions; and being reset even by a default `checkout --hard` is not desired. Currently, I have to shut down my IDE, copy away those files, restore the original versions, do some git work and then restore the saved files and start up my IDE again. That isn't handy.

I have repo which contains some application or workbench configuration. Since on my desktop things are a little different, those files differ. I would like git to ignore changes to that files upon `commit` or `status`; I would even like it to simply skip these explicitly named files when there would be need to overwrite them if not specially instructed.

```
git stash
```

seems to be no option, because it always stashes *all* changes, I cannot list the files to be kept aside. If I could, this wouldn't be handy, because before every action I have to stash manually a greater number of files and then unstash it again to make my application work again.

Symlinks aren't an option because I work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git update-index --assume-unchanged <files>`. Remember to use the `--no-assume-unchanged` flag to make Git check for changes again. More in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen mentions of `git update-index --assume-unchanged <my_file>` and quick googling says that it is indeed what might help you.

Comment: That's not really a useful answer, isn't it? A comment for that would be more appropriate in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Try git update-index --skip-worktree filename